# Find distance between 2 points in fastest way

Tags: performance, flash, actionscript-3, math, distance

This code calculates the distance between 2 points by using distance formula,  **Math.sqrt ( (x1 – x2)^2  + (y1 – y2) ^2)**. My first point has `mmx` and `mmy` coordination and second one has `ox` and `oy` coordination. My question is simple, is there any **FASTER** way for calculate this?

```
private function dist(mmx:int, mmy:int, ox:int, oy:int):Number{
  return Math.sqrt((mmx-ox)*(mmx-ox)+(mmy-oy)*(mmy-oy));
}
```

This is my code, Thanks for help.

```
public function moveIT(Xmouse, Ymouse):void{
            f = Point.distance( new Point( Xmouse, Ymouse ), new Point( mainSP.x, mainSP.y ) );// distance between mouse and instance 
            distancePro = Point.distance( pointO, new Point( mainSP.x, mainSP.y ) );// distance from start point 
            if (  f < strtSen ){ // move forward
                tt.stop(); tt.reset(); // delay timer on destination    
                mF = true;  mB = false;
                ag = Math.atan2((Ymouse - mainSP.y),(Xmouse - mainSP.x)); // move-forward angle, between mouse and instance
            }
            if (mF){ /// shoot loop
                if (f > 5){// 5 pixel
                    mainSP.x -= Math.round( (400 /f) + .5 ) * Math.cos(ag);
                    mainSP.y -= Math.round( (400 /f) + .5 ) * Math.sin(ag);
                }
                if (  distancePro > backSen ){// (backSen = max distance)
                    mF = false;         
                    tt.start();// delay timer on destination
                }
            }
            if (mB){ /// return loop
                if ( distancePro < 24 ){//  back angle re-calculation
                    agBACK = Math.atan2((y1 - mainSP.y),(x1 - mainSP.x));                   
                }
                mainSP.x += (Math.cos(agBACK) * rturnSpeed);
                mainSP.y += (Math.sin(agBACK) * rturnSpeed);
                if ( distancePro < 4 ){ // fix position to start point (x1,y1)
                    mB = false;
                    mainSP.x = x1; mainSP.y = y1;
                }
            }
        }
private function scTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void {// timer
            tt.stop();
            agBACK = Math.atan2((y1 - mainSP.y),(x1 - mainSP.x));// move-back angle between start point and instance
            mB = true;
        }
```

Also: `pointO = new Point(x1,y1);` set start point. I can not use mouseX and mouseY because of the way that the application is called by parent class, so I can just pass x and y to my loop.

Comment: I have an equally simple question: Have you determined that the speed of this code is an issue?

Comment: .. good point, I just want to know if there is any other method. For example an special Math formula or bit calculations over numbers..

Comment: My application is like a real-time interactive show whit numbers of instances. I need good speed.

Comment: Sure.  But the common saying "premature optimization is the root of all evil".  Don't try to optimize a section of code unless you have determined that it contributes a significant portion of your total runtime.  For instance, if this is only 1% of your runtime, there's no point.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I agree with you wholeheartedly, however in this case it's important to know the API well enough that you're not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a static function is a bit expensive. You can save that overhead by doing this:

```
private var sqrtFunc = Math.sqrt;

private function dist(mmx:int, mmy:int, ox:int, oy:int):Number{
    return sqrtFunc((mmx-ox)*(mmx-ox)+(mmy-oy)*(mmy-oy));
}
```

Comment: I'll ask the same thing I asked of @zzzzBov.  Have you tested this?  I have tested this and it seems to add about 15% overhead to reference through a variable in this way.  Can you show a code example that proves that the static function is more expensive than resolving a function through a variable?  More so,  can you show an example that proves that what you said is true?  I am sorry to challenge so hard, but this is the second answer I have seen on this thread that has actually been slower than what the OP asked to have sped up.

Comment: I tested it for some old version of the flash player. It may have changed at some point. I'll test it again soon and post here.

Answer (score 4):

I think that if you in-line your function instead of making an actual function call, it is the fastest way possible.

```
f = Math.sqrt((Xmouse-mainSP.x)*(Xmouse-mainSP.x)+(Ymouse-mainSP.y)*(Ymouse-mainSP.y)); 
distancePro = Math.sqrt((x1-mainSP.x)*(x1-mainSP.x)+(y1-mainSP.y)*(y1-mainSP.y));
```

Using `Point.distance` is WAY more readable, but it is several times slower.  If you want speed, you want to inline your math directly.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Point.distance`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html#distance%28%29)

```
d = Point.distance( new Point( x1, y1 ), new Point( x2, y2 ) );
```

It'll be executed in native code which is typically faster than interpreted code.

If you're in 3D space, use [`Vector3D.distance`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Vector3D.html#distance%28%29)

If you're doing collision detection, comparing the [lengths](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Vector3D.html#length) of vectors (2D or 3D) is quite common and can be resource intensive due to the use of the `sqrt` function. If you compare the [lengthSquared](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Vector3D.html#lengthSquared) instead, it will be much more performant.

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I did a quick timing of the two and yours comes up as 4x slower than the OP.

Comment: @KataxEmperorKatax: Did you validate this to be the case?  I'd like someone to tell me that they did, because when I tested it, I found this answer to be 4x slower than the one you are trying to optimize.

Comment: @BrianGenisio  -- if have any optimization idea on my function, please let me know .. : ] ,,

Comment: @KataxEmperorKatax: I don't have a better idea.  I think your original function is the most efficient.  But I measured the time to call both of these functions 10,000 times each.  In debug mode, it is 4x faster than `Point.distance` and in release mode, it is 10x faster than `Point.distance`.

Comment: @Brian Genisio, when you did your benchmarking, did you include instantiation of the `Point` objects? Creating many new objects will have an adverse affect on benchmarking, and typically for large data sets, a few objects can be reused.

Comment: @BrianGenisio  - I will test it again, .. It seems smoother with Point.distance now, thanks for your attention .. : ] ,,

Comment: @zzzzBov Well, that is not the code he has... he is newing up objects every time.  It doesn't matter anyways.  The overhead of the new `Point` objects does not cover the difference.  The Math way of doing things is still significantly faster than the `Point.distance` way.  Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/1233935

Comment: @KataxEmperorKatax might it be smoother because your new version does not make a function call but the old version did?  (`dist` was described as a function call but in the code you show, it is in-line)  Either way, we are talking about 4 vs 27 MILLIseconds for 10,000 executions.  How many times are you doing this that it makes a difference?

Comment: @BrianGenisio.  It is part of `stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, FL);` and always is running. I think, as you point, call a function makes that slow.

Comment: @BrianGenisio - I use `f = Math.sqrt((Xmouse-mainSP.x)*(Xmouse-mainSP.x)+(Ymouse-mainSP.y)*(Ymouse-mainSP.y));
   distancePro = Math.sqrt((x1-mainSP.x)*(x1-mainSP.x)+(y1-mainSP.y)*(y1-mainSP.y));` in my loop, it works faster. Your example was really usefull (gist.github.com/1233935). Thanks.